# How to make UITests-Runner able to access privacy-sensitive data

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode-ui-testing, xcuiscreenshot

I'm running an UITests case w/ `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` to save my test screenshot to Photos Album:

```
- (void)testExample
{
  XCUIScreenshot *screenshot = [_app screenshot];
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot.image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

but it crashed w/ error:

> ... XXXUITests-Runner[53905:8592232] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I've provided both NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription & NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription to my UITest Target & App Target.

Searched for a while, I can't figure out a way to let the UITests-Runner able to save image to Photos app so far, no UI level to let me press to allow it.

So, how can I achieve this, i.e., make UITests-Runner able to access privacy-sensitive data (Photos in this case)?

---

#### Sample Project Available Here:

[UITestRunnerIssueDemo](https://github.com/QADemo/UITestRunnerIssueDemo)

And below is the related error detail:

> Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2018-05-10 11:30:37.693
>   Test Suite 'UITestRunnerIssueDemoUITests.xctest' started at 2018-05-10 11:30:37.694
>   Test Suite 'UITestRunnerIssueDemoUITests' started at 2018-05-10 11:30:37.694
>   Test Case '-[UITestRunnerIssueDemoUITests testExample]' started.
>       t =     0.00s Start Test at 2018-05-10 11:30:37.695
>       t =     0.05s Set Up
>       t =     0.06s     Open com.kjuly.UITestRunnerIssueDemo
>       t =     0.10s         Launch com.kjuly.UITestRunnerIssueDemo
>       t =     3.08s             Wait for com.kjuly.UITestRunnerIssueDemo to idle
>       t =     6.10s Find the Target Application 0x60c0000dd5e0
>       t =     6.25s Tear Down
>   2018-05-10 11:30:43.948541+0800 UITestRunnerIssueDemoUITests-Runner[53905:8592232] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

---

*Btw, I know I can get the UITests screenshot that auto saved under AppData/Library/Snapshots folder, but it'll be convenient if I can get it from Photos Album, especially when doing so in real device, I'm not willing to download the App Container every time just for getting those screenshots (and also, I need high quality screenshot that saved).*

Comment: **Update**: I've sent a TSI and just got replied that _"Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that you are experiencing a known issue for which there is no known workaround at this time."_ And as suggested, filed a related bug report (#40317463), hope it will be handled in further Xcode version.

Answer (score 2):

I have exact same issue now, temporary workaround that work for me is to put the image save code:

```
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot.image, nil, nil, nil);
```

inside the app code like when you run it in debug mode.

Comment: Seems an option, but i wonder how do u get `XCUIScreenshot *screenshot = [_app screenshot];` inner host app? Or u just render view as screenshot image there? Personally, I don't like to involve test related code inner host app, but yeah, can be a temporary workaround. For now, i just do it in simulator & save it somewhere else instead of Photos app.

Comment: ya, render view as screenshot image, and keep it in  `#if DEBUG
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self captureScreen], nil, nil, nil);
#endif`